# swagger-editor line break in paths

Tags: rest, swagger, swagger-editor

For my ReST Service I created a yaml file using swagger-editor. The live preview is a nice feature which I use to export as pdf and then forward to our devs. The problem is now, that I have a more than one line path.
A nice feature would be to adjust the font-size in the live preview which is not possible I guess. Therefore, I am asking if a line break in the paths is possible.

Here is an example path which reflects the problem:
/thisIsTheBeginning/{andHereComesALongParameter}/stillNotFinished/{evenLonge}/doStuff:

When I export this as pdf from the browser it is visible until the first parameter:
Is it possible to have a line break in the paths?

Answer (score 0):

solved by changing the paper format to Din A3 on print as pdf!